# Regex search for string ".mp4" and "=mp4"

Tags: regex, grep

I am looking to crawl out entire site at work, and I need to look at every page for anything linking to a .mp4 or =mp4

How would I build a regular expression to search for .mp4 and not see the . as wildcard?

From what I understand, I could do .mp4|=mp4, but that just returns everything due to the .

Thanks ahead!

Comment: What language are you using?  There are probably existing tools that will help you, as this is not an uncommon task.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape any [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) to represent the literal character.

```
\.
```

So, for your example:

```
\.mp4|=mp4
```

Or, more condensed:

```
[.=]mp4
```

**Note:** you do not need to escape the dot when using a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: This  `grep "\.mp4|=mp4" file` does not give any result.

Comment: The OP mentions nothing about `grep`. Furthermore that example was taken from the OP and without parenthesis, is an incomplete alternation.

Comment: He does have  `grep` as tag in his post. This is ok `grep -P "\.mp4|=mp4" file`

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
grep "[.=]mp4" file
```